# How to set background image of SVProgressHUD Loader - IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, spinner, loader

I am using SVProgressHUD Loader. I want to use background image of loader. For that I don't have any clue that how to use this.

My code is this:

```
SVProgressHUD.setMinimumSize(CGSize(width: 120, height: 120));
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.darkGray)
SVProgressHUD.setRingNoTextRadius(40)
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.white)
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

I used this code but getting the error:
`SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage("test_icon.png")` -> error is : `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UIImage'`

I am Newbie on IOS development. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: the error is simply stating that, you need to provide a UIIMage and you are providing  a string, 
so make following changes
SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named:"test_icon.png"))

Comment: With this I get three error: 1-> Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage', 2-> Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil', 3-> Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'

Comment: if you have the image in your project, with exact name, you can use !
as Xcode is suggesting.

Comment: Yes I have an image on my project. What Xcode is suggesting also generates an error. SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named:"test_icon.png") ?? <#default value#>) what should I Write on default value

Comment: I suggested you to use ! operator instead of providing default value

Comment: If you wanna provide a default value then you can simple use 
SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named:"test_icon.png") ?? UIImage())

Answer (score 0):

You can used image in following way :

```
SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named: "your_image_name")!)
```

Comment: I already mentioned on comment that this will not work. Xcode generates an error

Comment: Please check your image in name "Asset.xcassets" folder. This is force unrapped ! . How same error occurred . Please double check / paste this line and replace image name .

Comment: and no extension needed in your image name . ex : SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named: "test_icon")!)

Comment: I check that image is added on assets. SVProgressHUD.setInfoImage(UIImage(named: "test_icon")!) Now Error is gone but image is not load on loader

Comment: Ok ! I checked it . Its not working here either ! May be its deprecated . I can suggest you 'NVActivityIndicatorView' library.That I recently used in my project,  you can add your custom image in view of NVactivator and animate it  . you can try .  https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView

Comment: Okay I will try that one. IS is possible to use small background image just behind the Loader so that loader will rotate over there.

Comment: yes , Its very simple to do , just create a loader view and make associate class as NVActivityIndicator . Then do a trick , just simply add an image view inside that view . It will work like charm .